# How to iterate through a mysql table just once in jdbc to build a count map?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have a mysql table with a column called state. Each row may have a different state of s1, s2, or s3.

The task is to build a map of state occurrences. One way of doing this is to build the following query strings:

```
select count(*) from NameOfTable where NameOfTable.state = "s1";

select count(*) from NameOfTable where NameOfTable.state = "s2";

select count(*) from NameOfTable where NameOfTable.state = "s3";
```

Then execute them.

But this approach iterate through the entire table 3 times. Is there a way 
of doing this by just iterating through the entire table once in jdbc?

Comment: I am using mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query runs over the table only once and produces all three counts.

```
select
    sum(case when state = 's1' then 1 end) as c1,
    sum(case when state = 's2' then 1 end) as c2,
    sum(case when state = 's3' then 1 end) as c3
  from NameOfTable
```

However, why do you want to go over the table only once? Speed, resource consumption, I/O? Your restriction seems quite artificial.

The alternative solution given by @Loc executes three queries, and may be faster than this one (Full Table Scan), if the table has indexes.

Comment: The table has a large amount of rows so I thought going over the table once will provide a better performance versus going through it multiple times.

Comment: Yes, that's called a Full Table Scan, and it's quite efficient when you are selecting more than 5% of the rows, or when there are no indexes. If this is your case, then you are right. However, if your table has an index which first column is `state` and also you are selecting 5% or less of the table rows, running three separate queries (aka Index Scan) could be more efficient.

Comment: I see. In my case, it is a table with a large amount of rows(the column of state can be indexed).  The very first time of the state count computation has to be a full table scan since each row has to be counted in order to get a correct count map.However, when there if there is a state transition for a single row and the count map needs to be recomputed, the solution given by @Loc will be more efficient.